# Java Android exception, error content must have a ListView whose id is android.R.id.list. android:id="@android:id/list Does Not fix Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, r.java-file

I'm receiving this message when launching my code, i have tried to use other answers but none seem to work for me, here is my Xml code for contents.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GamesURL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/GameName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GameName"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GameName"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/GameName"
            android:layout_below="@+id/GameName"
            android:text="URL" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GamesImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="GameDiscrip"
            android:src="@drawable/destiny" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GameName"
            style="GameName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivCard"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/GamesImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GamesImage"
            android:text="Game_name" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

Then this is my code for UseCustomAdapter.java:

```
public class UseCustomAdapter extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<Games> Games = new ArrayList<Games>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        setContentView(R.layout.scrollable_contents);

        ScrollView scrollable_contents = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollableContents);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contents, scrollable_contents);

        Games.add(new Games("Destiny", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/destiny"));
        Games.add(new Games("Saints Row", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/games/xbox-360/xt1490-saints-row-iv"));
        Games.add(new Games("Batman", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/games/xbox-360/xt1508-batman-arkham-origins"));
        Games.add(new Games("BattleField Hardline", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/games/xbox-360/xt1663-battlefield-hardline"));
        Games.add(new Games("Dynasty Warriors 8", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/games/xbox-360/xt1501-dynasty-warriors-8"));
        Games.add(new Games("DragonBall Xenoverse", "Xbox360",
                "http://www.graingergames.co.uk/games/xbox-360/xt1677-dragon-ball-xenoverse"));


        ListView lv = getListView();
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, Games);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }




    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
        Games G = Games.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, "User selected: " + G.getGamesTitle(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My code was running properly until i started adding in scroll view but adding that in should not return this kind exception as it has nothing to do with the actual list attribute, if you require to see my additional java or xml files that this code refer to then just ask thanks.

**Update**

Both `android:id="@id/android:list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list` do not fix error.

This is the logcat messages im receiving  for  android:id="@android:id/list :

```
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961): Process: com.Lewis.c3383583task2, PID: 961
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Lewis.c3383583task2/com.Lewis.c3383583task2.UseCustomAdapter}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at com.Lewis.c3383583task2.UseCustomAdapter.onCreate(UseCustomAdapter.java:31)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-15 09:40:18.050: E/AndroidRuntime(961):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: As is noted in the highly-upvoted answer on the duplicate question, change `android:id="@id/android:list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"`.

Comment: it does not fix issue no matter which way i use

Comment: You will not get "content must have a ListView whose id is android.R.id.list" if you use `android:id="@android:id/list"` for the `ListView`. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Selection/List). It is possible that you will have some other problems with your app, but those will result in different error messages and stack traces in LogCat.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Google search?

Comment: CommonsWare There is my logcat of errors for your suggestions, yes simon i have tried searching multiple times but still no look

Answer (score 1):

Rename id of `ListView` in your xml like this...

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: does not fix issue I tried that when searching other questions

Comment: Still the same error ? or the error changed now ? If not try to clean the project and re-install

Comment: I receive same error for both